# Dart angular2 with @canActivate

Tags: angular, dart

The tutorials about Dart and angular2 not enough to explain, how to protect and authorize my application.

How can implement `CanActivate` and Routers in dart in angular2?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112#issuecomment-153811572 contains a Plunker for a TS version that uses the same router as the current Dart version that demonstrates how to achieve that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sample that uses `CanActivate` to protect a component ([source](https://gist.github.com/kulshekhar/376b547133faa3afeb74fb2c15b26c78));

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:angular2/core.dart';
import 'package:angular2/router.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: const ['app_component.css'],
  template: '''
  <h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <div>
    <a [routerLink]="['Home']">home</a> - 
    <a [routerLink]="['General']">general area</a> - 
    <a [routerLink]="['Secret']">secret area</a>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  ''',
  directives: const [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: const [ROUTER_PROVIDERS],
)
@RouteConfig(const [
  const Route(
      path: '/', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true),
  const Route(path: '/secret', name: 'Secret', component: SecretComponent),
  const Route(path: '/general', name: 'General', component: GeneralComponent),
])
class AppComponent {}

@Component(
  selector: 'secret-area',
  template: '<div>Welcome to the secret area</div>',
)
@CanActivate(secretValidator)
class SecretComponent {}

secretValidator(ComponentInstruction next, ComponentInstruction prev) {
  if (prev.routeName == 'General') return true;
  window.alert('Unauthorized');
}

@Component(
  selector: 'general-area',
  template: '<div>Welcome to the general area</div>',
)
class GeneralComponent {}

@Component(
  selector: 'm-home',
  template: '<div>Welcome</div>',
)
class HomeComponent {}
```

This example allows you to load `SecretComponent` only if you are currently viewing `GeneralComponent` and not otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

On AngularDart 5 you can do it like this:

```
class MyComponent implements CanActivate {

  @override
  Future<bool> canActivate(RouterState current, RouterState next) {

   return Future(() => isLoggedIn);
  }
}
```